# Structure the same RDBMS Tables into MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

There is a requirement to convert the current structure of **MYSQL** to **MONGODB**. We have several tables in **MYSQL** which are interlinked via primary and foreign key sample DB Model as shown below. Can you share some insights how can we convert the same structure to MongoDB without disturbing the contraints. If possible how to convert the same sturcture in MONGODB with below tables example can anyone share please. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: .Making a one-to-one mapping ot relational tables to NoSQL collections is usually a bad design. Typically the number of collections is much less than the number of tables in according application.

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on how you are using the data. Since Mongodb is NoSQL, a database of documents, you can see each of your table as a collection of documents.

- A collection of jobs
- A collection of job_type
- A collection of account
- A collection of account type

From my perspective, all of your tables can be converted into individual collections,  Unless you have very unusual queries.

The only thing if you want to reference one collection to another, then you should probably include the reference to the collection to ease querying and reduce lookup time.

For example, in your candidate_profile, if you want to retrieve the `job_type`, you should include a `job_type_id` field in your `candidate_profile`.

If you want to easily find which job the candidate has, you should add a `job_id` field to the `candidate_profile`

If you don't, then your query becomes complicated and messy.

You should probably create the database with the collections then see whether it meets your requirement.

PS: I converted my application from mysql to mongodb as well.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried Domscheit and Someone Special for your valuable insights. I am new to MongoDB, can you give example with above data in MongoDB for better understanding if possible. I am bit confused because in the above example we have Account_Id which is foreign key in multiple tables like job , account_audit and candidate_profile so how do we keep this unique throughout the different collections?

Comment: add an `account_id` in all those documents if you want to `account` **from**  documents from other collections

Comment: got it thank you, can you share any good link to refer for MongoDB

Comment: we can't mention external links here in SO, but a quick "mysql to mongodb" search will bring you a lot of answers. From my personal experience, the people who develope the application using this database will be the correct person to speak to, since they are the one who are going to use it. Your database design, is not complicated, and can be simplified further if you use mongodb.